# c++:how do i add user input in while loop?

Tags: c++

how do i add a user input to my code? I want to create a simple while loop program that will increment the value input by the user by 2.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int a=2;
    while(a<=100)
    {
        cout<< "Value of a:  "<<a<<endl;
        a=a+2;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should probably start with code that “reads input by the user”, somewhere.

Comment: `cin >> a;` Surely your C++ book explains how to do that?

Comment: thank you for your answers, it definitely helped. we have our classes online now so I struggle catching up with our lessons because i have a slow internet.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand your question, but the syntax for user input would be cin >> variable here;

Comment: Include details or relevant links to improve the answer. In a bit you’ll have comment privileges too.

Comment: thank you for answering my question sir. it helped me a lot.